# Margin bottom has no effect on iOS CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a timetable and in chrome the class `.location` has margin bottom but on ios/safari nothing happens. (margin-bottom: 94px on .location )

This is my markup:

```
  <ion-scroll class="time-table" id="scroll" #scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
    <div class="line" [ngStyle]="{'left': leftTime, 'height': '100vh'}"></div>
    <div class="locations" *ngFor="let locations of dayselect; index as i">
      <ion-row class="location">
        <div class="gig">
          <div class="gig-box" *ngFor="let d of locations.eventSchedules; index as j" [ngStyle]="{'width': d.duration * minute + 'px', 'left': d.minutesFromStart * minute + 40 + 'px'}">
            <img src="assets/imgs/2.png" alt="">
            <h4>{{d.event.name }}</h4>
            <p>{{cut3(d.startTime) + '-' + cut3(d.endTime)}}</p>
            <ion-icon name="heart" class="fav"></ion-icon>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-row>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let locations of dayselect; index as i" class="loca">
      <h5 class="s{{i + 1}}" [ngStyle]="{'left': venuescroll}">{{locations.name}}</h5>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.line {
    width: 3px;
    z-index: -999999;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    background: $brand;
  }
  .location {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 94px; // <------- THIS ONE does not work
  }
  .gig {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 65px;
    .gig-box {
      background: $brand;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 999;
      height: 50px;
      .fav {
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 16px;

      }
      p,
      h4 {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
      h4 {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-top: 9px;
        top: 0;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        ;
        top: 25px;
      }
      img {
        height: 50px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the `display` value of the ion-row element?

Comment: The best way to debug this is to use Chrome's inspect while running ion(right click on where you want to change and click inspect). You can use `ionic serve --lab` to see the iOS version